# How can I enable right click in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

So I got this jquery min javascript file and it is blocking the right-click feature in my page. I've got no idea where to re-enable the right click feature, I've searched the whole code and nothing:
The first line I've searched at was this:

```
var Z=/^(?:input|select|textarea)$/i,et=/^key/,tt=/^(?:mouse|contextmenu)|click/,nt=/^(?:focusinfocus|focusoutblur)$/,rt=/^([^.]*)(?:\.(.+)|)$/;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fpfwu02z/

Comment: jQuery won't disable right click.. there is some other code that is doing ti... how are you saying jQuery is disabling it..

Comment: it could be that you have some code that is depending on jquery and is disabling the context menu event

Comment: I commented the whole code, only after commenting jquery src was when the click was re-enabled.
It has something to do wth the function: contextmenu

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/748gbost/1/ with jQuery but right click is working

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/748gbost/4/ - now right click is not working - so it is not jQuery that is the problem

Comment: You're right, I just found out it's another code.

Comment: Just had to comment:
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could not be jQuery, because jQuery does not do any such thing.

You should have another block of code somewhere which might be preventing the default action of the contextmenu event like below, remove that and you should be fine

```
$(document).on('contextmenu',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```