# How to extract data from div id using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to figure out how to do that, but I don't have a clue.
I need to get the text from a div using ajax and then use php to send it with SMTP, but I believe I just need to know how to make the ajax part.

Let's say I have this:

```
<div id="trajeto-texto1">
     <span id="resultado">
         <div class="calculo"><label>Distância: 0.00 Km</label></div>
         <div class="calculo"><label>Duração: 0 min.</label></div>
         <div class="calculo"><label>Custo: R$ 0,00</label></div>
     </span>                    
</div>
```

And I need to parse every single text inside the div id "trajeto-texto", or inside the span id "resultado".

It's like a php echo, but in javascript.

Console debugging, apparently there is nothing related to the form:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js:61 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
main.js:60 You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
33209.html:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: J is not defined
VM7253:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'geometry' of undefined
dados-do-formulario.js:100 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
http://sitesdemo.mghospedagem.com/ivam-entregas/3/images/bg.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
33209.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: J is not defined
33209.html:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: J is not defined
33209.html:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: J is not defined
33209.html:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: J is not defined
http://sitesdemo.mghospedagem.com/ivam-entregas/3/33209/css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, so I decided to give it a try, still no success:

```
 $(document).ready( function(){ //Quando documento estiver pronto
    $('#btnEnviar').click( function(){ /* Quando clicar em #btn */
        /* Coletando dados */
        var nome  = $('#nome').val(); 
        var email = $('#email').val(); 

var distance = $("#distance").text();
var duration = $("#duration").text();
var costs = $("#costs").text();         


        var msg   = $('#txtDetalhes').val();                                            
        var end1 = $('#1').val(); 
        var end2 = $('#txtEnderecoChegada').val(); 



        if(nome.length <= 3){           
            alert('Informe o seu nome');                        
            return false;           
        }    
        if(email.length <= 3){           
            alert('Informe o seu email');                        
            return false;           
        }  


        if(end1.length <= 3){           
            alert('Informe o endereço de partida');                        
            return false;           
        }                         
        if(end2.length <= 5){           
            alert('Informe o endereço de chegada');                        
            return false;           
        }      
        if(msg.length <= 5){           
            alert('Informe os detalhes');                    
            return false;           
        }                     





        /* construindo url */

/*

var urlData = "&nome=" + nome + "&email=" + email +  "&end2=" + end2 + "&distance=" + distance + "&duration=" + duration + "&costs=" + costs + "&msg=" + msg + "&end1=" + end1;

*/








 // extract all the values

    var data = [];
    $('#resultado span').each(function (index, item) {
        var id = $(item).attr('id');
        data[id] = $(item).text();
    });

    // do we have all the values?
    console.log(data);

    // POST the values to backend.php (adjust the URL).
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sendmailivam.php",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});




var urlData = { 
    "nome": nome,
    "email": email,
    "distance": distance,
    "duration": duration,
    "costs": costs,
   "msg": msg,
    "end1": end1,
    "end2": end2
};


        // Ajax 


        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "sendmailivam.php", // endereço do phpmailer
             async: true,
             data: urlData, // informa Url
             success: function(data) { // sucesso 
                 $('#retornoHTML').html(data);
             },
             beforeSend: function() { // antes de enviar 
                 $('.loading').fadeIn('fast'); 
             },
             complete: function(){ // completo 
                 $('.loading').fadeOut('fast');
             }
         });




    });    
});
```

TRIED AGAIN, I BELIEVE I DIDN'T MISS ANY POINT NOW, AND I SUSPECT THAT THE PROBLEM IS: THE DATA IS EMPTY. LOOK HOW I'M DOING IT:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //Quando documento estiver pronto
     $('#btnEnviar').click(function() { /* Quando clicar em #btn */
         /* Coletando dados */
         var nome = $('#nome').val();
         var email = $('#email').val();



         /*
                  var distance = $("#distance").text();
                  var duration = $("#duration").text();
                  var costs = $("#costs").text();
                 */


         // extract all the values

         var data = [];
         $('#resultado span').each(function(index, item) {
             var id = $(item).attr('id');
             data[id] = $(item).text();
         });

         // do we have all the values?
         console.log(data);



         var msg = $('#txtDetalhes').val();
         var end1 = $('#1').val();
         var end2 = $('#txtEnderecoChegada').val();



         if (nome.length <= 3) {
             alert('Informe o seu nome');
             return false;
         }
         if (email.length <= 3) {
             alert('Informe o seu email');
             return false;
         }


         if (end1.length <= 3) {
             alert('Informe o endereço de partida');
             return false;
         }
         if (end2.length <= 5) {
             alert('Informe o endereço de chegada');
             return false;
         }
         if (msg.length <= 5) {
             alert('Informe os detalhes');
             return false;
         }

         //Construindo URL
         var urlData = {
             "nome": nome,
             "email": email,
             "data": data,
             "msg": msg,
             "end1": end1,
             "end2": end2
         };


         /*
            var urlData = {
                      "nome": nome,
                      "email": email,
                      "distance": distance,
                      "duration": duration,
                      "costs": costs,
                      "msg": msg,
                      "end1": end1,
                      "end2": end2
                  };

         */



         // Ajax 

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "sendmailivam.php", // endereço do phpmailer
             async: true,
             data: urlData,


             // informa Url
             success: function(data) { // sucesso 
                 $('#retornoHTML').html(data);
             },
             beforeSend: function() { // antes de enviar 
                 $('.loading').fadeIn('fast');
             },
             complete: function() { // completo 
                 $('.loading').fadeOut('fast');
             }
         });




         // do we have all the values?
         console.log(data);




     });
 });
```

Comment: Why ajax? console.log($.trim($('#resultado').text())); Now you can put this in variable, and send it via ajax....

Comment: What sorcery is this?

Comment: The error log (with resource loading errors) you posted is completely unrelated to the problem of posting values from the dom via ajax. The error indicates a problem with Google Maps resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I interpret your question a bit and maybe it's what you want:

**1 How to extract the values from HTML?**

The trick is do add one more dom element, to make the selection of the actual values easier.

```
<div id="trajeto-texto1"> 
    <span id="resultado">
        <div class="calculo">Distância: <span id="distance">1.00</span> Km</div>
        <div class="calculo">Duração: <span id="duration">2</span> min.</div>
        <div class="calculo">Custo: R$ <span id="costs">3,00</span> </div>
    </span>    
    <button id="SubmitButton">Send</button>
</div>
```

This allows to select the "values" without worries (split or regexp the value from the text of the label).

You simply use `$("#distance")` to select the dom element by ID with jQuery.
To get the value you append `.text();`.

```
var distance = $("#distance").text();
var duration = $("#duration").text();
var costs = $("#costs").text();
```

Or a bit better use .each() for iteration over the dom elements and build your data object, like so:

```
// extract the values
var data = [];
// iterate over dom element inside span (= item)
$('#resultado span').each(function (index, item) {
    // from this item, get the id
    var id = $(item).attr('id');
    // from this item, get the text, which is the value
    data[id] = $(item).text();
});

console.log(data); // browser console = debug display = open it with key F12
```

The console output is: `[distance: "1.00", duration: "2", costs: "3,00"]`.

Ok, we made sure `data` contains the values we want to send... now: let's send.

**2 How to send the values over to PHP?**

Well, that depends. You could do a POST or GET request. Hmm, lets go with a POST:

```
// your data looks like this, we got this already
var data = [distance: "1.00", duration: "2", costs: "3,00"];

// post data array to your PHP backend
$.post("backend.php",
    data: data,
    function(data,status){
      // do anything with response
});
```

---

Full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/b6w0ckmj/2/

```
$('#SubmitButton').click(function (evt) {

    // extract all the values

    var data = [];
    $('#resultado span').each(function (index, item) {
        var id = $(item).attr('id');
        data[id] = $(item).text();
    });

    // do we have all the values?
    console.log(data);

    // POST the values to backend.php (adjust the URL).
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/html/",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hm... not so sure that var distance = $("#distance").val(); will work. On the other hand -> text() will work. ;) span is not input.

Comment: Great answer, that's it, the word is "extract". There must be a way to extract everything from the div "resultado", instead of getting stuff from each span.

Comment: What you are looking for is "jquery serialization of a dom element". Normally this is done on forms to easily send the form values. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914985/javascript-how-to-serialize-a-dom-element-as-a-string-to-be-used-later - you can also fetch the label text from the dom element and then start to match() things.

Comment: Or you could also use a jquery selector for the spans inside of resultado span and add every span with its ID to an object. Then you can post that object. See a demo of that in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/3gts8y68/).

Answer (score 1):

Jens A. Koch, it's not working. I'm using the javascript like this:

```
var urlData = "&nome=" + nome + "&email=" + email +  "&end2=" + end2 + "&distance=" + distance + "&duration=" + duration + "&costs=" + costs + "&msg=" + msg + "&end1=" + end1;


        /* Ajax */
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "sendmailivam.php", /* endereço do phpmailer */
             async: true,
             data: urlData, /* informa Url */
             success: function(data) { /* sucesso */
                 $('#retornoHTML').html(data);
             },
             beforeSend: function() { /* antes de enviar */
                 $('.loading').fadeIn('fast'); 
             },
             complete: function(){ /* completo */               
                 $('.loading').fadeOut('fast');
             }
         });
    });    
});
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging using the javascript console? Sharing that information would help. Formatting your data to JSON as geekychick suggested looks like a good idea too!

Comment: Just did that, updated.

Comment: I've added a working example over at JSFiddle and updated my answer accordingly - this works uses .each() to grab the values. Please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/b6w0ckmj/2/

Comment: You are mixing GET and POST styles here. urlData contains a string, which you can easily append to your GET target url. Decide, what you want to do: GET or POST.

Answer (score 1):

@user3692451 this is for your comment below

data needs to be an object:

```
var urlData = { 
    nome: nome,
    email: email,
    end2: end2,
    distance: distance,
    duration: duration,
    costs: costs,
    msg: msg,
    end1: end1
};
```

Comment: Still not working, is it the comma's fault?

Comment: It's not extracting any data.

Comment: I'm using the code in the page especified in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247511/how-can-i-enable-right-click-in-jquery

Comment: I think the keys need to be in quotes i.e. "nome": nome

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Still not working. Can you visit the page to help me understand the js errors?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to extract all the texts from a div, no matter how nested they are, you can do something like:

```
function getTexts(rootNode){
    var stack = Array.prototype.slice.call(rootNode.childNodes,0);
    var texts = [];
    var currentNode;
    while(currentNode = stack.pop()){
        if(currentNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && 
           currentNode.textContent.match(/[A-z0-9]/)
          ){
            texts.push(currentNode.textContent);
        }
        if(currentNode.childNodes.length > 0){
            stack.push.apply(stack, 
                Array.prototype.slice.call(currentNode.childNodes,0)
            );
        }
    }
    return texts;
};
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/xyy674x4/3/)

Comment: The ID goes here `var texts = [];` ?

Comment: No, you just need to call getText passing the root element of the DOM portion you want to process, the function returns you an array containing all the text strings found. Take a look at the linked JSFiddle for a working example.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that seems great, man, I didn't see that getelementbyid in the end, I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: and how can I send the data using POST?

Comment: It's because using the way described here is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, I had to put the element inside a form and use a hidden input after the element. So it got like this:

```
    <div id="trajeto-texto1"> 
 <form method="post" action="33209/33209.html">

        <span id="resultado" style="font-weight:bold">


        <div class="calculo">Distância: 1.00 Km</div>
        <div class="calculo">Duração: 2 min.</div>
        <div class="calculo">Custo: R$ 3,00 </div>
    </span>  
   <input id="resultado" type="hidden" name="resultado" />

   </div>
```

Also had to make some adjusts in the javascript, but nothing reaaally different from Jens A. Koch's answer.